# If a and b are dependent variables, what's the probability of a,b both happen?

Tags: probability

Bayes' theorem tells me

$$P(a \cap b)= P(a)P(b|a) \tag{1}$$

which I interpret as a happens, and b happens on condition of a. Then why don't we need to consider b happens first, ie.

$$P(a \cap b)= P(a)P(b|a)+P(b)P(a|b) \tag{2}$$

?

Further, if I need to find the probability of a or b, but not both, should it be

$$(1-P(b|a))P(a)+(1-P(a|b))P(b) \tag{3}$$

?

Comment: A) The RHS of your second expression has two terms. They are both equal to the LHS so the LHS = 2 * RHS. B) Not clear to me where that last expression came from but  the probability of A or B  is equal to the probability of the union of A and B, P(A U B) ,  which is equal to P(A) + P(B) - P(A and  B)..

Comment: "$P(a \cap b)= P(a)P(b|a)$" is not Bayes' theorem but a fundamental result called the (general) product rule or the chain rule; indeed you can use it to prove Bayes theorem. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)#Two_events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have already answered the title question in your first statement. But let's add a bit more to it:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(B|A)P(A) = P(A|B)P(B)$$

As @Glen_b pointed out, this relationship, upon which Bayes theorem is based, has only to do with how probability is defined. Because the 2nd and 3rd equations are equivalent, it must be true that the *order* in which $A$ and $B$ does not come into play.

If you *do* want to consider time ordering, then you would be looking for something like this:

$$P(A_{t'>t} \cap B_t) = P(B_t|A_{t'>t})P(A_{t'>t}) = P(A_{t'>t}|B_t)P(B_t)$$

In the 2nd equation, you are actually conditioning on an event which happened in the future, which is ok as you might be trying to figure out something that happened further back in time.

As @mlofton pointed out, and this is another fundamental result of the definition of probability,

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

Nevertheless, I do believe your last equation, which expand out to

$$P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B)$$

The explanation of the formula for $P(A \cup B)$ can be seen in this Venn diagram:

[image]

is that the last term corrects for having double counted the intersection area when you "add up" the areas in the "A" part and the "B" part. For "and not both" you need to actually cut the intersectcion part out. So subtracting $P(A \cap B)$ again does the trick.

To add one last thing: do be careful about confusing *dependency* with intersection. A and B can have an intersection while being independent.

Comment: I'm much clear now. FYI, I added numbers to my equations, so it's easier to reference them.